# Foursquare autologin when facebook (Logged In) and foursquare (Not Logged In) are using in the same window?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, foursquare

Let me explain in detail with screenshots.

Case 1: I logged in with facebook account & open Foursquare in another tab of same window, it gets logged in automatically. See below screenshot 'disableFacebookAutologin' cookie is not set so I think it gets logged in automatically.

[image]

Case 2: I logged out from Foursquare, see below screenshot 'disableFacebookAutologin' cookie has set. So I think Foursquare autologin was stopped. Henceforth whenever I open Foursquare & Facebook in same window the auto login is stopped in Foursquare.

[image]

We are using FoursquareAPI.class.php to get the location checkins for the particular users. Is there any option to set the cookie 'disableFacebookAutologin' as 1 for this php API? 
We want Foursquare not to get auto login with Facebook id unless we click sign in or Login with facebook button. So kindly assist our request and do the needful.

Thanks,

Arularasan

Comment: You cannot set cookie for another domain like foursquare. ALso, foursquare has no option for disableFacebookAutologin. You can see complete scenario in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155367/foursquare-autologin-when-facebook-logged-in-and-foursquare-not-logged-in-ar/24155708#24155708)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no way to do that. That cookie setting property is on Foursquare side. When you click foursquare login button, you will be redirected to foursquare login signin system, and the control is Foursqaure now. The scenario is below;

1. If user signin with your foursquare app for the first time, user will be asked for permission, and then fb login will be checked. IF user is logged in facebook in current browser user authomatically will be logged in
2. If user already signed in before by using your foursquare app, fb login will be checked and signin authomatically if user logged in to fb.

Finally, you cannot set cookie for another domain (foursquare.com). Also, Foursqaure has no option to disableFacebookAutoLogin in their apis. As same as in php libraries here;

1. [foursquare-php](https://github.com/chriswoodford/foursquare-php/search?q=disableFacebookAutologin&ref=cmdform)
2. [php-foursquare](https://github.com/hownowstephen/php-foursquare/search?q=disableFacebookAutologin&ref=cmdform)
3. [foursquare-api-client](https://github.com/jcroll/foursquare-api-client/search?q=disableFacebookAutologin&ref=cmdform)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.  

 1. First of all I opened the chrome window to login facebook account.
 2. After Facebook login, I opened foursquare login (Without login) in new tabs.
 
Actually without login the foursquare, it gets redirect to logged in.  Can you please explain that how to stop this autologin in foursquare.

Comment: You cannot stop foursquare autologin, because, foursquare controls that. When you try to open any page of foursquare, it uses fb sdk to check user is logged in to fb or not. If you are logged in, you will be logged in to foursquare also. I think, you need to ask your self : "Whay should I prevent user to be authomatically logged in foursquare if they logged in fb also?" . Do you have any reason for that?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But in our app by the client reqs, we need to stop foursquare autologin until the user is logged in via foursquare if facebook and foursquare are using the same window at any browsers. Can you have any possibility to stop this actions.

FYI, We are using Foursquare.API.class.php files.

Comment: Ok, you are using correct php lib but you cannot stop that autologin. That is the behaviour of foursquare. When you click login, the control will belong to foursquare. That is oauth protocol. If user is first time signing to your system, foursqaure will raise a popup for permission, and then will autologin.